# Ember Fixture Adapter not setting record ID

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Okay, so I'm trying to copy an existing model as a new model instance (so all attributes are the same except for its ID. In my template, I have an action, `copy`, that passes the model in scope at that place in a list to the controller so it can be copied. My controller code is below. I appear to be able to create a new record, but its ID is set to 'fixture-0', 'fixture-1' etc., and calling `.save()` on it (see below) results in an error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'serialize' of undefined
```

As I'm currently stubbing the models for development, I'm using the fixture adapter, as it seems that's got something to do with the problem.

Controller code:

```
REApp.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    copy: function(current_model){
      var self = this;
      console.log(current_model);

      var new_record = this.store.createRecord('cycle', {
        railsId: null,
        accountId: current_model._data.accountId,
        //lots more attributes here
      });

      new_record.save();
      console.log(new_record);
    }
  }
});
```

`console.log` call from the controller, showing `new_record`:

```
a {id: "fixture-0", store: a, container: t, currentState: Object, _changesToSync: Object…}
```

Note: even if you take out the `.save()` method call from the controller, this new record is created with the `id` set to a string. If `.save()` is *not* called (and thus no error raised in the controller), then the new record appears in the ember inspector's data panel with its ID set to a string as above.

This is only my third Ember app (and my first with 1.3.0), so open to the idea that I'm just doing it wrong.

Edit: 
Here's the model definition. If it's relevant, I've had other errors returning both `varOfModelObject.save();` and `this.content.save();` from the controller since, so def thinking it's related to the FixtureAdapter.

```
REApp.Cycle = DS.Model.extend({
  //id: DS.attr('number'), not needed with fixtures
  railsId: DS.attr('number'),
  siteId: DS.attr('number'), //all numbers here are ints unless noted
  clientId: DS.attr('number'),
  accountId: DS.attr('number'),
  startAt: DS.attr('datetime'),
  endAt: DS.attr('datetime'),
  chargePerEvent: DS.attr('decimal', {defaultValue: 0.0}),
  createdAt: DS.attr('datetime'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('datetime'),
  scheduleYaml: DS.attr('string'),
  allDay: DS.attr('boolean'),
  repeat: DS.attr('boolean'),
  exceptionDates: DS.attr('string'),
  additionalDates: DS.attr('string'),
  charge: DS.attr('number'), //decimal in rails
  chargePeriod: DS.attr('string'),
  oldRegularEventId: DS.attr('number'),
  scheduleHuman: DS.attr('string'),
  bagLimit: DS.attr('number'),
  untilDate: DS.attr('number'),
  sendToWebfleet: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
  contractId: DS.attr('number'),
  hourlyRate: DS.attr('number'), //decimal in rails
  hourlyCharge: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0.0}), //decimal in rails
  doubleEvent: DS.attr('number'),
  //these are used for the simple view 
  weekdays: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: null}),
  weekends: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: null}),
  //data below this needed for associations
  clientName: DS.attr('string'),
  commentBody: DS.attr('string'),
  siteAddress: DS.attr('string'),
  carer1Id: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: null}),
  carer1Name: DS.attr('string'),
  carer2Id: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: null}),
  carer2Name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('user', {async: true}),
  items: DS.hasMany('item', {async: true})
});
```

Comment: Alex I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying the problem is.  The id can be a string, that's a perfectly acceptable format.  It's assigning an `id` since it's fixture data and it knows it isn't backed by a real data source, so it gives it a dummy unique id.  So is the real problem that you're getting the can't call serialize of undefined error on save?

Comment: Hi, yeah, I had wondered if the 'fixture-$number' was the default, that's good to know. So yeah, the error is that the save call is returning undefined for the record. Could that be because the new record is simply fixture data?

Comment: would you mind including your model definition above

Comment: It's a bit of a massive one, but I've added it above.

Comment: @AlexLynham Did you ever get this fixed? I'm running into a similar issue trying to unit test a model.

Comment: @JulianLeviston it is because the fixture adapter isn't backed by dynamic data I believe. You can create new objects in memory but they are distinguished from other objects by that 'fixture-' prefix. I've now come to the conclusion with Ember apps that it's barely worth hanging around at the fixture stage because it differs quite a lot from working with real data.

Comment: @AlexLynham maybe answer your own question? :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, when working with fixtures, you can create new objects in memory, but they are distinguished from the hard-coded fixture objects by a `fixture-` prefix in their object ID. As a result of this, you may find behaviour being a little screwy - perhaps this will be fixed in a newer version of Ember Data, but in the meantime the answer seems to be to get off using fixture data and move to a live data situation as quick as possible in your dev process.

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me what you get, yes in the console you gonna get an error yet it works, simply override the method createrecord as follows:

```
REApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    mockJSON: function(store, type, record) {
      try {
        record.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        return this._super(store, type, record);
      }
      catch(err) {

      }
    },
  }
);
```